# Authentication doesn't return valid result from query?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

I was writing code to ask for login information & valid it, jump to another page if it is valid. But why it always stays in the login page?
Index.php:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require('../model/database.php');
 require('../model/admin_db.php');

 $action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');

 if ($action === NULL) {

    $action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');

    if ($action === NULL) {
      $action = '';
    }
 }

 if(!isset($_SESSION['is_valid_admin'])){
   $action = 'get_admin';
 }
 switch($action){
    case 'get_admin':
        $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
        $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
        echo $username;
        echo $password;
        echo is_valid_admin_login($username, $password);

        if (is_valid_admin_login($username, $password)){
            $_SESSION['is_valid_admin']=true;
            include ('admin_menu.php');
        }
        else {
            $login_message = 'you must login to view this page.';
            include ('adminlogin.php');
        }

     break;
```

admin_db.php:

```
<?php
function is_valid_admin_login($username, $password) {
   global $db;
   $password = sha1($username . $password);
   $query = 'SELECT username FROM administrators
            WHERE username = :username 
                            AND password = :password';

   $statement = $db->prepare($query);
   $statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
   $statement->bindValue(':password', $password);
   $statement->execute();
   $valid = ($statement->rowCount() == 1);
   $statement->closeCursor();
   return $valid;
}
?>
```

And there is no issue with connecting database.

Comment: I don't see you redirecting.. Oh, and *finally* someone that uses `prepared statements`.

Comment: maybe bacause you include 'adminlogin.php' again _after_ the `end if`?

Comment: I don't know the api to connect with; `mysqli_` as per another of one your questions. or is it in fact PDO? and where's the HTML form for this? too many unknowns, too many past questions with no accepted answers.

Comment: you should work with header('location: ...') rather than includes here.

Comment: and yet another who expects a magic answer out of nothing, bye bye

Comment: Your `index.php` code is incomplete and causes a parse error. Until you fix that, nobody can help you without making assumptions about your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using  `include ('adminlogin.php');`  after `if else` statement. So every time this is opening `adminlogin.php`.

And to redirect the page you can use `Header` too.

Comment: oops, that's typo. sorry. It shouldn't be there.

Comment: I fixed this admin.php commenting out $password = sha1($username . $password); but it doesn't work for customer login page which using similar format.